# Do the phrases "valuable for" and "valuable to" have the same meaning?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *valuable for* and *valuable to*?

> The workers are very **valuable for** the company.
>
> The workers are very **valuable to** the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally "valuable for"  indicates the properties or aspects that make something valuable orm the uses to which it can be put, while "valuable to" indicates the people or entitites who valu e the thing. For example:

- > Gold is valuable for its rarity, ductility, conductivity, and beauty
- > Gold is valuable for making jewelry and circuit connectors.
- > Gold is valuable to jewelers, circuit designers, and collectors.

The sentence "The workers are very valuable for the company." does not follow this pattern, adn I find it awkward at best. I would much prefer:

> The workers are very valuable to the company